# php scandir() - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [file]

Tags: php, glob, scandir

I have a server running PHP Version 5.4.16 and am trying to use scandir to list files within a directory. I am having a hard time figuring out what the issue is. I've tried both ../store/dir_to_scan and /root/store/dir_to_scan. I've also tried using both glob and scandir as you can see below both to no avail. If I remove the dir_to_scan directory it will list the directories inside of /root/store which is what I find most puzzling of all. I've also chmod'd the folders and files to 777 just to make sure it wasn't a permissions issue. I receive an error of "Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [file] => /root/html/test.php [line] => 5 )" also upon running with correct directory setup.

Thanks for any help.

**Directory Setup**

```
/root/html //where php script is run
/root/store/dir_to_scan //files I need to list
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?
 #$files = glob('../store/dir_to_scan/*', GLOB_BRACE);
 $files = scandir("/root/store/dir_to_scan/");
   foreach($files as $file) {

      //do work here
      if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
                continue;
       }
    echo $file . "<br>";
}
print_r(error_get_last());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be silly but try supplying a trailing slash at the end of:

/root/store/dir_to_scan ->

```
$files = scandir("/root/store/dir_to_scan/");
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, unfortunately the same issue exists with or without the trailing slash. :/

Answer (score 0):

this should to solve your problem

```
$carpeta= "/root/store/dir_to_scan";
    if(is_dir($carpeta)){
        if($dir = opendir($carpeta)){
            while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.htaccess'){
                  echo $file;  //or save file name in an array..
                 //  $array_file[] = $file;

                }
            }
            closedir($dir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the same code i use for this problem, and i live in a spanish country.. and $carpeta is the only spanish word

Comment: Well this got me a little closer to success. It can read /root/store just like the other script but will not list files in /root/store/dir_to_scan. That said it no longer throws the "Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [file] => /root/html/test.php [line] => 5 )" error.

Comment: maybe is a problem whit permision, check it.. also try whith this:
echo exec("ls /root/store/dir_to_scan");

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  8 09:27 dir_to_scan
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  8 07:35 dir_to_scan2
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  8 07:18 dir_to_scan3
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  7 22:18 dir_to_scan4

Comment: did you use the function with dir_to_scan2?,
also you could change user/group of dir and files to apache.

Comment: I will eventually, but currently not just testing it. It works on another server of mine which is also puzzling with the same permissions just a newer version of php 5.5.